# Using Prepared PDO statements

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm running queries using the PDO prepared statement, MySQL db. When I run a query, I haven't found a way to know the number of affected rows if any, I've tried `rowCount()` but still to no avail.

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM publications WHERE pub_journal = '$j' AND pub_issue = 'CURRENT'");
$stmt1->execute();
```

How can I find the number of affected rows?

Comment: $result = $stmt1->fetchAll(); then you can use a $count= count($result) or use the $count = $stmt1->rowCount();

Comment: That's not how you use prepared statements.

Comment: Also affected means the rows are changed somehow. No rows are changed by a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rowcount()` should only be used [for DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), though it may work for SELECTs in some cases.  What you can do is this, though:

```
$res = $stmt->fetchAll();
$count = count($res);
```

And `$count` will hold the number of rows.

Comment: @Don'tPanic technically correct, but per docs, isn't best practice.

Comment: @Don'tPanic In any case, answer edited to acknowledge your comment.

Answer (score 1):

`rowCount` should work if your database is MySQL. The fact that it hasn't worked for you indicates that your query may be failing, or that it does not return the number of rows you expect it to.

The [PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) suggests the following approach to find the number of rows:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned.

This should work with a prepared statement as well as with `PDO::query()`.

You can modify your original SQL to be used as a template, so that it can take either `COUNT(*)` or `*` (or even better, a list of the specific columns you need).

```
$sql = "SELECT %s FROM publications WHERE pub_journal = ? AND pub_issue = 'CURRENT'";
```

Notice the `?` in the SQL. This is a placeholder to which the `$j` variable will be bound when the statement is executed with `execute([$j]);`. When you concatenate your variables into the SQL string (like `...WHERE pub_journal = '$j'...`) you really aren't getting much of the benefit of prepared statements.

With this, you can prepare and execute your count query:

```
$count_stmt = $db->prepare(sprintf($sql, 'COUNT(*)'));
$count_stmt->execute([$j]);
```

Then get the count with:

```
$count = $count_stmt->fetchColumn();
```

After you do whatever you need to do with the count, you can execute the actual SELECT query by specifying which columns you want rather than `COUNT(*)`.

```
$select_stmt = $db->prepare(sprintf($sql, '*'));
$select_stmt->execute([$j]);
```

Comment: thanks @EatPeanutButter, it worked for me.
'Don'tPanic', I think you've just shown me a better way to handle queries. Thanks all, I love Stackoverflow